# Java Method Problems

Tags: java, methods

*Solved by answers below* I'm currently taking AP Computer Science, and I'm trying to construct a program out of everything they're giving me, but I think that I may be putting something in entirely the wrong place. The BankAccount method creates a new bank account. The main method is creating a bank account for KevinC. The GetBalance method should return the balance of KevinC's bank account. I'm getting this as an error:

```
BankAccount.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(c.GetBalance);
                            ^
  symbol:   variable GetBalance
  location: variable c of type BankAccount
BankAccount.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        return balance();
               ^
  symbol:   method balance()
  location: class BankAccount
```

And here's the code:

```
public class BankAccount {
    public BankAccount(String acctPassword, double acctBalance) {

        String password = acctPassword;
        double balance = acctBalance;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BankAccount c = new BankAccount("KevinC", 800.00);
        System.out.println(c.GetBalance);

    } 
    public double GetBalance() {
        return balance();
    }


}
```

Comment: You're forgetting the method call's parenthesis `()`. It should be: `System.out.println(c.GetBalance());`. Note the `()` at near the end. Voting to close as a trivial error.

Comment: method invokations need paranthesis afterwards `c.GetBalance()`. without the paranthesis the compiler thinks that you are trying to acces a class member variable. Also as a sidenote i´d try to stick to the java convention, which means methods are starting in lower case. This will increase the readibility of the code for yourself and others.

Comment: I think that the key to your question is to look seriously at any and all lines of code that the compiler flags you on, and try to see how it deviates from correct lines that you'll find in any Java textbook or tutorial. A quick review of how methods are called would fix up the first error for you.

Answer (score 2):

These are syntax errors, you mixed method calls and fields access, check this :

```
public class BankAccount {

double balance ;

    public BankAccount(String acctPassword, double acctBalance) {

        String password = acctPassword;
        balance = acctBalance;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            BankAccount c = new BankAccount("KevinC", 800.00);
            System.out.println(c.GetBalance());

        }

    public double GetBalance() {
            return balance;
        }

}
```

Also, your `balance` field was local to the constructor, I moved it out so that your method can access it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add the `()` to `System.out.println(c.getBalance())` like so.

Also in your `getBalance()` method, you are trying to return a method that doesn't exist. You want to return the variable `balance` instead.

You should also move your `password` and `balance` variables out of the constructor so your other methods can access them.